# How to save data before partial segue?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, segue

(default data is X, and dynamic data is Y)
How to keep my data Y when i segueway?

When i'm on the "seguewayed" view, i press "back" instead of "done" and the previously data Y is set to X... how can i keep this Data Y?

FYI in prepareForSegue i send my DATA Y to the destinationViewCtrlr.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution,

```
- (void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
//whatever action i want to do before the view goes away
}
```